# Extending auth.User model, proxied fields, and Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, proxy-classes

(Edit:  I know that there's a totally separate feature in Django called "Proxy Models".  That feature doesn't help me, because I need to be able to add fields to UserProfile.)

So I'm starting a new Django app and I'm creating a UserProfile model which is a extension of django.contrib.auth.models.User and failed attribute requests back to User, as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')

    def __getattr__(self, name, *args):
        if name == 'user' or name == '_user_cache':
            raise AttributeError(name)

        try:
            return getattr(self.user, name, *args)
        except AttributeError, e:
            raise AttributeError(name)
```

This works fine in general, but breaks when I try to use a `User` field in UserProfileAdmin.list_display.  The problem is in the admin validation code here:

```
def validate(cls, model):
    """
    Does basic ModelAdmin option validation. Calls custom validation
    classmethod in the end if it is provided in cls. The signature of the
    custom validation classmethod should be: def validate(cls, model).
    """
    # Before we can introspect models, they need to be fully loaded so that
    # inter-relations are set up correctly. We force that here.
    models.get_apps()

    opts = model._meta
    validate_base(cls, model)

    # list_display
    if hasattr(cls, 'list_display'):
        check_isseq(cls, 'list_display', cls.list_display)
        for idx, field in enumerate(cls.list_display):
            if not callable(field):
                if not hasattr(cls, field):
                    if not hasattr(model, field):
                        try:
                            opts.get_field(field)
                        except models.FieldDoesNotExist:
                            raise ImproperlyConfigured("%s.list_display[%d], %r is not a callable or an attribute of %r or found in the model %r."
                                % (cls.__name__, idx, field, cls.__name__, model._meta.object_name))
```

The problem is that while an instance of UserProfile will have proxied fields, e.g. email, the UserProfile class itself doesn't.  Demoed in the Django shell:

```
>>> hasattr(UserProfile, 'email')
False
>>> hasattr(UserProfile.objects.all()[0], 'email')
True
```

After some digging, it looks like I'd want to override django.db.models.options.Options.get_field for UserProfile._meta.  But there doesn't seem to be a non-hacky way to do this (I have a very hacky solution right now, which involves monkey-patching UserProfile._meta.[get_field, get_field_by_name])...any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Just updated to note that I have a hacky solution.  But a non-hacky one would be great, if it exists.

Comment: Oh, by the way, showing us your `admin.py` file could have been useful here =P

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple. Here's an example of a UserProfile model from a library we use:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    accountcode = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

That's it. Don't bother with the `__getattr__` override. Customise the admin interface instead:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile

class StaffAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]
    # provide further customisations here

admin.site.register(User, StaffAdmin)
```

This allows you to CRUD the `User` object, with access to the UserProfile as an Inline. Now you don't have to proxy attribute lookups from the UserProfile to the User model. To access the `UserProfile` from an instance of `User u`, use `u.get_profile()`

Comment: If you want get_profile() to work you need to set the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE setting in settings.py to the correct model as well.

Comment: Thanks, that does solves the admin problem, but leaves me having to deal with the annoying extra `.user` whenever I want to access a user attribute on a profile.  I have another codebase where I'm constantly doing things like `profile.user.X` or `user.get_profile().Y` and, in this new codebase, I think a little `__getattr__` ugliness in one place might be worth the increased consistency everywhere else.  If nothing else, it'd be a productivity increase during development.

Comment: The user object only has a few fields on it anyway. Just define some @properties on the userprofile which delegate to the user. I really don't like the `__getattr__` method for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proxy class, it is a relationship. See more on [Proxy Model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)s, which are a subclass of the original model, with the `Meta.proxy = True`

Comment: Yes, I just updated the title because I realized that it might cause exactly this confusion.  I know "Proxy Models" are a different thing, but they don't help me in this case, because I want to be able to add fields to UserProfile.  So while you're right that my title could have been clearer, my question stands.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a field from User to be in list_display in your UserProfileAdmin, try:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user__email',)
```

If you want to have it as part of the form, add it into your UserProfileForm as an extra field, and validate it in the form.

Comment: Thanks, but using field lookups in list_display like that actually doesn't work, at least not in Django 1.2.5.